# Unexpected results from GARCH Processes

Tags: time-series

I'm playing a bit with Time Series and I've been trying to estimate [Garch Processes](http://value-at-risk.net/garch-processes/) from different time series. Are `TimeSeriesModelFit` and `EstimatedProcess` returning accurate results?

An example:

```
proc = GARCHProcess[0.1, {0.02}, {0.04}];
data = RandomFunction[proc, {1, 250}];
tsm = TimeSeriesModelFit[data, {"GARCH", {1, 1}}];
estimatedProc1=tsm["Process"]
estimatedProc2 = 
  EstimatedProcess[data, GARCHProcess[1, 1], 
    ProcessEstimator -> "MaximumConditionalLikelihood"]
```

> ```
> GARCHProcess[0.00551636,{0.022469},{0.923687}]
> GARCHProcess[0.0112017,{0.0463092},{0.844707}]
> ```

A few questions:

- Why are these 2 functions returning different results?
- How do I know which one is the best fit? (I can't seem to get stats for Estimated Process like I do with `TimeSeriesModelFit`.)
- How do I know there is one with a good fit?
- Are these 2 functions rubbish and if not what do I need to do to improve the quality for the results?

P.S. question for WRI: when are we getting EGARCH, GJR, GARCH for Student T, etc.?

**Updated with the same methods**

```
proc = GARCHProcess[0.1, {0.03}, {0.05}];
data = RandomFunction[proc, {1, 250}];
tsm = TimeSeriesModelFit[data, {"GARCH", {1, 1}}];
estimatedProc1 = tsm["Process"]
estimatedProc2 = 
  EstimatedProcess[data, GARCHProcess[1, 1], 
    ProcessEstimator -> "MaximumConditionalLikelihood"]
```

> ```
> GARCHProcess[0.113584,{0.0000239773},{0.0198394}]
> GARCHProcess[0.0395911,{5.86338×10^-13},{0.659115}]
> ```

Also the results can change when run at different times.

Comment: Unfortunately, they return different results whatever the method. Updated.

Comment: Note that this gives different answers when run at different times because you're generating new data each time using `RandomFunction`. If you want your code to always generate the same data, use `SeedRandom` first.

Comment: Good point. I still can't explain the difference or know which one is the best. Maybe I need to programme a MLE function?

Comment: I've done a few tests with different Garch Processes and EstimatedProcess return higher MLE every time. I'm still not sure it's very accurate still.

Comment: I am unsure of the specifics, but in general `TimeSeriesModelFit` will try to use more "lightweight" algorithms than `EstimatedProcess`, since it is designed to check many different models rather than one specific model, like `EstimatedProcess`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan R. I'm also going to compare the results against R and Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Xavier,

Two things to keep in mind: estimating a GARCH(1,1) with 250 points may not find reliable parameters.

Try increasing the length of the input time series. For example, using 20,000 points I get these results from both approaches (even if the second does not converge fast enough):

with TimeSeriesModelFit:

> GARCHProcess[0.0901242, {0.0395382}, {0.113799}]

and with EstimatedProccess:

> GARCHProcess[0.0929155, {0.0368543}, {0.0901876}]

Differences hint at different implementations... but Mathematica is a collection of handy black boxes, so this shall remain a mystery until the release of OpenMathematica...(yeah, right)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for this Paramecium. I didn't check for higher number of points. Interestingly EstimatedProcess returns the same results as Matlab. Matlab is way faster though!

Comment: Glad I could help. I've looked again at this problem in Matlab 8.3.0.532(R2014a), with the Financial toolbox v5.3 and beware, because although it is a faster numerical computation, the results are not stable (as expected). I do not know how to make a reliable diagnosis of the matlab algorithm, so please beware of taking speed as a sign of accuracy or reliability. Cheers!